# Number of representations by the norm in a division algebra corresponding to endomorphism rings of elliptic curves

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, quadratic-forms

Let $E$ be a supersingular curve over a field of characteristic $p$ with endomorphism ring $\mathcal O_D$ which is a maximal order in a division ring $D$ over $Q$ ramified at $p$ and $\infty$.

The norm defines a (positive definite) quadratic form in $4$ variables, let us call it $Q(x,y,z,w)$. Given an integer $n$, is it known what the number of solutions to $Q(x,y,z,w) = n$ is? I would like this to depend only on $p$, $n$ and the size of the unit group in the maximal order.

For instance, if $D$ were the Hamitonian quaternions (over $\mathbb Q$), then this is classical and Wikipedia has a formula essentially in terms of $\sigma(n)$, the sum of divisors on $n$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Number_of_representations). They don't give the formula for the maximal order but I am really interested in the maximal order and even just the case of $n$ prime might be good enough.

Comment: If $p$ is large then there are many nonisomorphic maximal orders in $D$, and the representation numbers are usually going to be different, so I am not sure how you would even formulate the answer. In particular your goal of having a number that depends only on $p$, $n$ and the size of the unit groups is probably impossible to fulfill.

Comment: Would a uniform bound be more plausible?

Comment: Yes, but probably not very useful. For instance, for $n$ prime and $p$ large, the best lower bound will probably be $0$.

Comment: I was more interested in upper bounds!

Comment: Won't the generating function be a level $N$ weight $2$ Eisenstein series ? Thus of the form $\sum_{\gamma \in SL_2(Z/NZ)} C_\gamma E_2(\gamma(z))$ so you want to know $N$ and an upper bound for $\sum |C_\gamma |$